# Unable To Connect Sql Server from Database from Power BI Desktop

Tags: sql-server-2012, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server

While trying to Connect SQL server from Microsoft Power BibDesktop , Following error occurred

We encounter an error while trying to connect
Detail: “Required attribute type cannot be empty ( C:/..../Microsoft.Net/.../machine.config). This is configuration issues with the file machine.config

I tried to resolve by reinstalling .Net framework -and restart. But Could no resolve the issues

What might be the possible solution for this issues ?

Comment: Is your `machine.config` modified in any way?

Comment: Nope. i haven't . This is issues in my production server , All .Net Application are running absolutely fine . SSRS Server is also working fine

Comment: Please post the full error message and details, if available. Is anything else mentioned in the Windows Event Viewer (often under "Application" or "Administrative Events")?